# Any way to dynamically change the height of a publisher action?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, publisher-action

I'm creating a UI component that I would like to use as a custom publisher action as well. It is a two-step wizard that expands vertically when a user clicks in a form field. I suspect that dynamically resizing the height of a publisher action is not possible, but I wanted to check and to find out if anyone has come up with a crafty work-around.

Comment: Could you use JavaScript to resize the window?